# Как урезать репозитарий Git?

Tags: git

Имеется репозитарий размером 1.5 Гб, хотелось бы его скопировать и оставить в новом репозитарии только скажем последний год.
Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43487392/4827341 . и, да, урежьте, пожалуйста, вопрос, создав отдельно второй про hg.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace